# ¿Por qué el timeout en php se activa antes de tiempo?

Tags: php, html5, session, sesiones

Estoy trabajando con sesiones en php, creando 4 paginas llamadas: 1,2,3 y 4. Paso a traves de la paginas desde 1 a 4 y cuando regreso de 4 a 1 al pasar por 2 cierra sesión, aunque el tiempo de inactividad no se haya agotado.

```
//1
Aqui establezco los keys

<?php

SESSION_START();

$_SESSION["usuario"]="javier";
$_SESSION["contrasena"]="1234";
$_SESSION["timeout"]=time();

echo "
<section id=recuadrop>SKYNET</section>
<section id=recuadro>sesion iniciada con usuario, contraseña y hora establecidos</section>";

?>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//2
Aqui defino el timeout
<?php

SESSION_START();

echo "<section id=recuadrop>SKYNET</section>
<section id=recuadro>Bienvenido,"." ".$_SESSION["usuario"].
"<br>Tu contraseña es:".$_SESSION["contrasena"].
"<br>Tu hora de ingreso (seg.) fue:".$_SESSION["timeout"]."</section>";


$inactividad=600;
$inactividad2=time()-$_SESSION["timeout"];
if($inactividad2>$inactividad){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:4.php");}
?>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//3
Aqui elimino el registro de usuario
<?php

```
SESSION_START();

unset($_SESSION["usuario"]);
unset($_SESSION["contrasena"]);

if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
echo "<section id=recuadrop>SKYNET</section>
<section id=recuadro>Eliminaste el registro de tu nombre de usuario <br>";}

if (!isset($_SESSION["contrasena"])){
echo "Eliminaste el registro de tu contraseña</section>";}

?>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//4
Aqui cierro sesion
<?php

```
SESSION_START();

session_destroy();

echo "<section id=recuadrop>SKYNET</section>
<section id=recuadro>Has cerrado la sesión</section>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo ocurre porque estás destruyendo la sesión en la página 4 antes de regresar a la página 1.

Cuando regresas de la página 4 a la página 1, el código en la página 2 se ejecuta nuevamente y verifica si el tiempo de inactividad ha superado los 600 segundos. Dado que la sesión ya se ha destruido en la página 4, la variable `$_SESSION["timeout"]` ya no existe y produce un error. Como resultado, se destruye la sesión nuevamente y se redirige a la página 4.

Para solucionar, debes verificar si la variable `$_SESSION["timeout"]` existe antes de realizar la verificación del tiempo de inactividad. Si no existe, puedes establecerla nuevamente con el tiempo actual.

Ejemplo para la página 2:

```
<?php
SESSION_START();

echo "<section id=recuadrop>SKYNET</section>
<section id=recuadro>Bienvenido,"." ".$_SESSION["usuario"].
"<br>Tu contraseña es:".$_SESSION["contrasena"].
"<br>Tu hora de ingreso (seg.) fue:".$_SESSION["timeout"]."</section>";

$inactividad = 600;
if (!isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
    $_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
} else {
    $inactividad2 = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
    if ($inactividad2 > $inactividad) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: 4.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Es cierto, el key timeout se elimina al cerrar sesión. De ahi que obligatoriamente conduce a cerrar sesión nuevamente. Gracias